# how to stop app building in xctest?

Tags: xctest

I am new to XCTest UI Automation, whenever I run my xctest code it calls main code and starts building app on my iPhone is there any objective C code or settings using which i can make xctest code independent ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to manipulate the scheme? Look into the _Build_ section where you can define the dependencies. Hope that helps.

Comment: @macmoonshine can you please give some more details

Comment: Sorry, you have not to modify the scheme. Go to the _Build Phases_ tab in the target settings, where you ca find a section _Target Dependencies_. Remove the desired dependencies from the target.

Comment: This helped me but when i run it through "xcodebuild test", app is building

Answer (score 0):

If you go to "Target dependencies" for your UI testing target, you can remove the app as a dependency - this will stop the app being built when you're running UI Tests. Be careful though, the xctestrun file expects there to be a .app file for it to install on the device, so you will need to have previously built the app in the same derived data directory that you're building the UI Testing target to.